# How to get javascript regex to return everything in the string as part of the matches, not just the matched parts

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

Test string:

```
*This* is a test.[15] I would like[16] To figure _out how_ to do this.[20]
```

RegEx:

```
/\[\d+\]|\*.*\*|_.*_/gu
```

Actual Results:

```
Match 1: *This*
Match 2: [15]
Match 3: [16]
Match 4: _out how_
Match 5: [20]
```

Desired Results:

```
Match 1: *This*
Match 2:  is a test.
Match 3: [15]
Match 4:  I would like
Match 5: [16]
Match 6:  To figure 
Match 7: _out how_
Match 8:  to do this.
Match 9: [20]
```

Comment: You can use a [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the split sequence: [`s.split(/(\[\d+\]|\*.*\*|_.*_)/u`](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoIwEADQna@4jbbGIiYaE@Pi5s7WkoZAgWrDEXqFhX@vvP19m7UJ7eJmOq@PlLwlCPCCXFSjCwJcgAbIBpKqvNXwgQ2j78C7n1XlvYYKoXdDXCwYjAQjbgYIoUOg40t1vdT5M8tanAJ6Kz0OLMgwe0esYFrp7qTrXQsptNiNFIYXkcveebILe@NRmonzlP4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider this approach that splits the input with capture group and uses `filter` to remove empty match from the start.

```js
const s = '*This* is a test.[15] I would like[16] To figure _out how_ to do this.[20]'
console.log( s.split(/(\*[^*]*\*|_[^_]+_|\[\d+\])/).filter(Boolean) );

/*
[
  "*This*",
  " is a test.",
  "[15]",
  " I would like",
  "[16]",
  " To figure ",
  "_out how_",
  " to do this.",
  "[20]"
]
*/
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group

  - `\*[^*]*\*`: Match substring wrapped in `*`
  - `|`: OR
  - `_[^_]+_`: Match substring wrapped in `_`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\[\d+\]`: Match `[number]` part
- `)`: End capture group

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a pure regex implementation.
In your current regex, you have not included matching for the "non-special" words so they are not showing up in the match.

Only modifying the regex you already have. you would need something as follows

```
/\[\d+\]|\*.*\*|_.*_|.+?(?=\[|_|\*)/gu
```

Here the addition of  `.+?` is a non-greedy match until the regex encounters any of the characters mentioned in the positive lookahead `(?=\[|_|\*)` which is '[' or '_' or '*' set based on your example.